# Can there exist an injective function from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying high and low to find an injective function from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)$, but to no avail. I've tried all sorts of polynomial functions, exponential functions, etc. but I've had no luck so far. Can anyone provide an example of such a function, or prove that such an injection is not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you can take $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,\infty)$
using $f_1(x)= e^x$. 
Then you can translate that by $2$ using $f_2(x)=x+2$ and obtaining $(2,\infty)$.

For last step shrink $(2,\infty)$ by $f_3(x)=\frac{1}{x}$to end up with$(0,\frac{1} {2})$.

All these were $1-1$ so the composition of all of them is injective.

Moral of the story try sucessive transformations, do not try to do at one step. By using injective function you are transforming to equivalent domains which may have been more easy to transform. The idea would be to compose and each time shrinking the domain.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask how you'd do it if the interval was $[0,1]$? The above method won't work because it would always end up with a singularity.

Comment: With this method you have a injective function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1]$ since $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ is contained in $(0,1]$ Just do a translation. If $f$ is such injective function take $g(n+1) = f(n)$ for all natural numbers with the $0$ and $g(x) = f(x)$ for the rest. See that in this way we have an injective function, that takes all the range of $f$ in this case $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. But, doing this process we have defined $g$ for $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, so, we can make $g(0) = 0$ and we have an inhective function that goes to $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ hence, injective to $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 6):

Let's try with $y=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\arctan(x)$

Comment: For $x=-2$, it gives approximately $1.3524$, which is not in $(0,1)$, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, now it is right

Comment: Yes, it does work! May I ask how you came up with it? Is there a systematic way you used?

Comment: Well, thik to the graph of the $\arctan$: it is bijective from $\mathbb{R}$ to a limited open interval. Then it's easy obtain $(0,1)$ by translations and multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{x}{1+|x|})$.