# How to prove $|[a, b]| = |\mathbb R|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove $|[a, b]| = |\mathbb R|$, i.e. there are equally many points on a finite line segment than on the whole number line? Could  one use the Cantor-Schröder-Dedekind theorem, which tells as that if we have injections $A\to B\to A$, then $|A| = |B|$? Then it only remains to prove that there is an injection $\mathbb R\to [a, b]$.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564056/can-there-exist-an-injective-function-from-mathbb-r-to-0-1). You can compose this injective with a bijective map from $(0,1)$ to $(a,b)$. The composed map will be an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[a,b]$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that cardinality of the reals = cardinality of $[0,1]$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660997/proving-that-cardinality-of-the-reals-cardinality-of-0-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s easy to get a one-to-one onto map between $\Bbb R$ and an *open* interval $\langle a,b\rangle$, you can use $\arctan$ for instance, suitably scaled, to do it. Then there are standard tricks to get the endpoints into the act. Nothing as deep as Schröder-Bernstein should be necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call Schröder-Bernstein particularly deep, though.

Comment: For my level of smarts, @HenningMakholm, it’s deep enough.

Answer (score 4):

There is an injection (bijection, in fact) from $\mathbb R$ to $(-1,1)$: $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

Now, transform the interval $(-1,1)$ into $(a,b)$.